# ¿De dónde proviene la frase "vientos huracanados"?

Tags: gramática, méxico, frase, origen

En México he escuchado muchas personas adultas (de 50 años en adelante) usar la frase "¡Vientos huracanados!" en lugar de decir "genial", por ejemplo. Incluso he escuchado gente más joven usar simplemente "¡vientos!".

Mis dudas son: ¿cómo surgió esta frase?, ¿solo se usa en el centro del país?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece que para cualquier mexicano al escuchar o al manifestarse con la expresión, ¡*Vientos huracanados*! esta remitiendo necesariamente a algo positivo, festivo, alegre o animado, donde se muestra contento y jubiloso, por algo o alguien al que le ha sucedido un acontecimiento o ha salido triunfante de una situación y que le ha hecho entusiasmarse.

La frase "vientos" es como decir "¡qué padre!", ¡genial!, ¡que bueno!, y en su versión larga es la expresión, ¡*Vientos huracanados*!.

Aunque actualmente en México casi todo el mundo conoce la expresión ¡*Vientos huracanados*!, algunas teorías apuntan a que podía provenir del norte, a partir de la Ciudad de Juárez y de los fuertes vientos que allí se originan, y que a su vez, **¡Vientos huracanados!**, derivaría de otra expresión,  “**Me hace lo que el viento a Juárez**”, más antigua y que muchos relacionaron en su momento con el propio "Benito Juárez" (antiguo presidente de México en varias ocasiones, del 21 de enero de 1858 al 18 de julio de 1872​).

El enlace de la figura de "Benito Juárez" con la misma ciudad de "Juárez", provocó la confusión entre los mexicanos, confusión que hasta el día de hoy persiste, ya que pensaban que la expresión  “**Me hace lo que el viento a Juárez**” se refería al mismo "Don Benito", entendiendo con ello, que ni los "**vientos más huracanados**", podían despeinar a "Don Benito Juárez", pues este tenía fama de ir siempre muy bien peinado, más bien repeinado, cuando en realidad la referencia era hacia la ciudad y no hacia el personaje.

Así cuando se dice; “**Me hace lo que el viento a Juárez**”, significa y se esta hablando entre otras cosas, de como una persona salió victoriosa o triunfante de una situación adversa o difícil. De esta manera, la idea de salir victorioso de algo, triunfante o ganador y su celebración, junto con aquella otra idea, extendida entre muchos mexicanos, que "**ni los vientos más huracanados**" podían despeinar a "Juárez", "Don Benito Juárez", evolucionó hasta convertirse en la expresión **¡Vientos huracanados!** y aún siguió evolucionando, para expresarse en un solo monosílabo, **¡Viento!**, para referirse a una victoria, un triunfo, a algo grato, bueno, genial..., "algo padre".

Comment: Esto es incorrecto. Es cierto que la frase "Me hace lo que el viento a Juarez" existe pero no es el origen de ¡Vientos huracanados!
El origen se relaciona con el hecho de que muchas personas alargan la última silaba en señal de entusiasmo además de que agregar detalles no relacionados a una frase es muy común. Asi en lugar de ¡Bien! escuchamos ¡Bieeeeen! y luego, por casualidad, agregamos "tos" y se convierte en ¡Bieeentos! Y si el viento es muy fuerte ¡Bieeeentos huracanados!

Answer (score 0):

«Vientos huracanados» viene de «¡Bien!». No le busques tres pies al gato. Y la expresión «Le hizo lo que el viento a Juárez» simplemente significa otra cosa.

Answer (score 0):

Según yo viene del ataque que hacia Mazinger Z en la caricatura de los ochentas. Cuando Mazinger lanzaba una potente corriente de aire como ataque decía VIENTOS HURACANADOS!
En México vientos es usado.como slang , equivalente a decir: si, estoy de acuerdo, vamos, va que va!
Los niños en los ochentas simplemente lo adaptaron y de ahí se difundió a través de los años.

Busque en you tube Mazinger Z vientos huracanados y lo verán con sus propios ojos.